# Trimble Net R9 Base Station Receiver File Structure

Tags: gps, trimble, base-station

We just installed our new GPS Base Station Net R9 receiver that replaced our old 5700 receiver. The old 5700 used Trimble's GPS Base software, which the new Net R9 does not. My first problem that I can't seem to figure out is the file structure. With the old GPS Base software we were able to set the data logging system to write the files in folders that went Year -> Month -> Day -> hour. It was a nice clean structure. The new Net R9 logs all files in one folder where we have it set for every hour. This is going to be a massive folder after a while. Does anyone have any experience with the Net R9 file structure and how to get it to write like the old GPS Base software? Below are some pictures. Thanks in advance!!
[Trimble 5700 GPS Base File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHmId.jpg)
[Net R9 File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDILS.jpg)

Comment: Check the firmware version, upgrade if necessary you can change the formats that are written, see from page 89 -  http://www.trimble.com/infrastructure/netr9-gnss-reference-receiver.aspx?dtID=support (documentation)

Answer (score 1):

It all has to do with the ftp push, change it from flat to type/yyy/ddd/site. I had assumed it was all in the data logging settings, and wasn't looking at the ftp push.